# I'd like to sell my interest in a money judgment/garnishment - not sure of market for that

Tags: wage-garnishing, cash-flow

I am a landlord and just filed with the county sheriff for garnishment of a bad debt - a prior tenant.  The tenant has a job and is being garnished - I just don't want to wait fo so long to get the full amount (Around $6000)

Is there a market for these things?  I know people do discount these revenue streams -just not sure how I can find a buyer.

I'd probably discount it significantly as I need the money to pay real estate taxes by the end of the year.

Comment: There's definitely a market for things *like* this, though it may be more effective for larger debts. I'll see if I can drag up the WSJ article I saw.

Comment: Yeah - I am aware of things like royalty payments and lottery winnings, stuff like that.  Just trying to find a buyer who can make a good return on this and so I can get the money now.  I wonder if a bank would give me a loan using the judgment as collateral.  Doubtful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, if you're considering taking a 50% discount on a revenue stream you feel is low risk because you're having cash flow issues paying those property taxes - I'd recommend you seriously separating these two unrelated concerns and deal with each in most financially astute manner individually.

1. You'll keep more of your hard earned cash
2. You don't have the hassle factor and uncertainty of trying to become proficient in an esoteric field of financial knowledge by Christmas!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to look at companies that buy annuities and give you a lump sum.   They exist to do this for lawsuit payments, lottery winnings, etc.

I'm not sure what the fees would be on a relatively small payout of $6K but try [searching for "converting annuity to cash"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=convert+annuity+to+cash) and the first several hits were all firms looking to buy structured payment settlements for a lump sum.

They make their money by paying less than the present-day value of the annuity, so you will get less money this way than collecting your payments slowly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sell it to a collection agency. I just googled and this is the first results: [CollectYourBills.com](http://www.collectyourbills.com/)

Comment: Well, those people specialize in collection - I don't need their services - as the sheriff has already attached to their wages - it is just going to take too long to collect.  The collection companies take far too much off the top or buy for so great a discount because of the low expectation of collection - this case is a bit different - there is much less risk - the collection is already happening.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to work with a collection agency or law firm that specializes in collections. They'll buy the debt from you for something like 10-25% depending on the state and whether they are interested in something this small.

People who don't pay rent and get wages garnished for $6k are a bad risk. They'll discount the judgement significantly since the risk of bankruptcy is probably pretty high.

Comment: In this case the bankruptcy thing is not really an issue IMO - the garnishment collections are made specifically to keep the monthly costs for the debtor low.  10-25% is the rate for people who have skipped town/hard to find.  The garnishment in this case is already set up.  I would have expected (and willing to agree to) 50% - but not 10-25% - that is out of line with the lower risk.

Comment: You might end up taking a smaller hit by just taking out a line of credit somewhere and paying it off with this revenue stream. Talk to your bank?

Comment: I agree with fennec: you'd be effectively paying $3k to borrow $6k for what, a few years?  It's somewhere over 20% interest, at least. If you own a rental property and have good credit yourself you could almost certainly just borrow the money you need at a lower rate.